# Using a dynamic custom UITableViewCell in XCode 4.2, with Storyboards and UISeachDisplayController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I've used Xcode 4.2 to create a storyboard-based iOS application.
One of my screens contains a UITableViewController, using dynamic custom cells.

So far - so good.

Now, I wanted to add a UISearchDisplayController to allow filtering my list.

For some reason, the UISearchDisplayController won't display my custom cells, and I can't find a way to force it...

This is what my cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"QueueListCell";
    QueueListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[QueueListTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    assert(cell);

    if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {
        indexPath = [_indexPathsForSearchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSDictionary* itemDict = [_ListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.labelQueueName.text = [itemDict objectForKey:kQueueName];
    cell.labelQueueNumItems.text = [[itemDict objectForKey:kQueueNumItems] stringValue];

    return cell;    
}
```

Any thoughts on how to get this working? I mean, my UISearchDisplayController table DOES show the correct number of results (I know that since I can click on them, and I added an NSLog to let me know what I'm clicking on...)

This is my table view
[image: This is my table view]

This is how the search display table looks like...
[image: This is how the search display table looks like...]

My problem/question is how to make the UISearchDisplayController table view show my custom cells?

Any help appreciated...

Reuven

Comment: You can always check the difference using the reference comparison of tableView.

Comment: note my problem is that for some reason the searchResultsTableView doesn't display my customer cells. That's what's I'm trying to solve (see images I added to the post)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Answer specific to query

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

For Complete example, have the [sample code from apple's site](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848).

[Step by step illustration](http://sugartin.info/2011/12/07/uisearchdisplaycontroller-custom-uitableviewcells/)

Comment: Spark, you're my hero! :-) so, so, so frustrating. Yet, so so so simple and elegant to fix! THANKS!

Comment: That initially, I tried dequeuing a cell from the method parameter tableView (that knows nothing of my custom cells)... With @Spark's answer, I changed my code to dequeue the cell _always_ from self.tableView - the table the _knows_ about my custom cells...